# How to use first 10 layers of pre trained model like VGG19 keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, transfer-learning, vgg-net

I am trying to use first 10 layers of VGG19 for transfer learning for an image classification task.

I tried this to use first 10 layers but when I add it to a sequential model and show the summary I am getting an error.

```
basemodel = VGG19(include_top = False)    
x = basemodel.layers[-10]    
model = Sequential()    
model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(32,(7,7),input_shape = (256,256,3),activation = 'relu'))    
model.add(x)    
model.summary()
```

Comment: Please format your codes and errors for better reading

Comment: Can you show error codes?

Comment: it shows model has to be built before compiling

Answer (score 0):

I run the model and the error is :
`ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer block4_conv1: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 256 but got shape (None, 250, 250, 32)`

Remove the input shape from `keras.layers.Conv2D`
and add it to basemodel:

`basemodel = VGG19(include_top = False,input_shape=(256,256,3),weights='None')`

or if you want to use Imagenet:

`basemodel = VGG19(include_top = False,input_shape=(256,256,3),weights='imagenet')`

fit the model and let me know any errors occured.

Answer (score 0):

You took only one layer from the VGG model and connected them the wrong way.
Here one of the proper ways to do it:

```
basemodel = VGG19(include_top = False)    
model = tf.keras.Sequential(basemodel.layers[:10])
model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (7, 7), activation = 'relu'))
model.summary()
```

Note that first layer of `VGG` is an `InputLayer` so you propably should use `basemodel.layers[:11]`.

And note that to fine-tune your models it's better to fix weights of VGG layers:

```
for layer in model.layers[:10]:
    layer.trainable = False
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is instead of adding first 10 layers you have added the 10th layer from the top.Also, the input to that layer should have channels as multiples of 256. Just replace the code with this:

```
model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(256,(7,7),input_shape = (256,256,3),activation = 'relu'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

vgg19 = tf.keras.applications.VGG19(weights='imagenet',
                                    input_shape=(224, 224, 3),
                                    include_top=False)
vgg19.trainable = False
model_out = vgg19.layers[6].output
x = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(model_out)
vgg_output_1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation="softmax")(x)
vgg_model_1 = tf.keras.models.Model(vgg19.input, vgg_output_1)
vgg_model_1.summary(show_trainable=True)
```

Here the first 6 layers of VGG19 are called and then after flattening, a dense layer is used to classify the image into three categories.
Use the Keras [Model Class](https://keras.io/api/models/model/).